# StackLayoutPanel Shows white ends at the rounded corners

Tags: css, gwt, rounded-corners, gwt-widgets

I'm using GWT's `StackLayoutPanel` and trying to round the corners of its headers by applying `border-radius` attribute in the following CSS rule:

```css
.mm-StackPanelHeader {
  padding-left: 7px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  background: #d3def6;
  border: 0.5px solid #bbbbdd;
}
```

When collapsing the header items, the borders don't cover over each other completely, showing ugly white cornered ends.

How to fix this?

Here's the [output's snapshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/805/stackoverflow.jpg/), for a reference.

Comment: the rounded corners are created using the headers's background image. try to use [`StackPanel`](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwStackPanel) instead. it seems to provide the looks you're after out-of-the-box.

Comment: @EliranMalka Thanks I know about `StackPanel`, but it's the old version of `StackLayoutPanel`, and has less methods where the latter one has the news methods and improvements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `StackLayoutPanel` was a definitely a newer version than `StackPanel`.

But I used the latter in this case because there was no other way, and it worked like a charm!

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're going for the [old widgets' look n' feel](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwStackPanel), achieving the exact same result will inevitably involve replacing images and messing with the widgets' layout properties (e.g applying negative margins, altering offsets).

Having said that, I managed to get a quick CSS-based solution that seem to target your needs, and is free of further manipulations. I'm sure a more accurate solution is available, as this attempt is far from perfect, but it should provide you with a good starting point.

#### Abstract

To simulate the old widgets' looks:

- Round up the top corners for the item headers.
- Apply a background color to the underling container, to avoid those *ugly white corners*.
- Use top round corners on that container as well, to avoid *ugly blue corners* on it as a result of the background color applied.
- Reset the bottom padding of the header items to re-center their content.

#### Implementation

Add the following rules to your stylesheet:

```css
.gwt-StackLayoutPanel,
.gwt-StackLayoutPanel .gwt-StackLayoutPanelHeader {
    background-color: #D3DEF6;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.gwt-StackLayoutPanel .gwt-StackLayoutPanelHeader {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

#### Illustration

Here's an snapshot of the final result, as created by manipulating the CSS properties on the GWT showcase live example:

[image: stack layout panel modified]

Comment: Can you link the final result again?

Comment: there's no link to a final result, as - sadly enough - no gwtFiddle exists (yet), but you surely can open the [`StackLayoutPanel` example in the GWT showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwStackLayoutPanel) and mess with the CSS inside the browsers' developer tools.

Comment: Haha! Yeah, messing up is the right combination of words to utter out regarding *GWT* coding coming right out of  in-lab Google experiments...